# How to wait the result of API calls in a foreach in angular

Tags: angular, observable

I would like help to wait the result of API call in a foreach loop in angular.

Until the foreach doesn't end my datagrid loading icon is visible, and then when all the foreach call ends, the datagrid `datasource = this.actifs_machines`, and the loading icon is hidden.

My code is:

```
private loadActifsMachines()
  {
    this.ActifModelEvent.forEach(
      actif => {
        const actifsValues =  this.actifsService.getActifsMachines(actif.atf_Id)
        .pipe(map(res => this.matchesLabel(res,actif)))
        .subscribe(
          {
            next:(actifMachinesData) => { this.actifs_machines = [ ...this.actifs_machines, ...actifMachinesData];},
            error:(error) => {console.log(`Error getting List Actif Machines [actif_id:${actif}]. Error:${error}`)},
            complete: () => { console.info('complete')}

          });
      this.subscriptionAggregator$.add(actifsValues);
      });
  }
```

How to return `this.actifs_machines` when all the calls are done, and also can I have an error aggregator to catch any error, if in some API call, an error occurs.

Comment: Maybe you could use forkjoin, https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/forkJoin

Comment: Hi  user1075296, thanks  for the help. I will check.